# What's the shortest phrase to describe Q&A sites like Stack Exchange?

Tags: phrase-request

What's the shortest phrase to describe sites like Stack Exchange? It's not a forum, it's Questions-and-Answers site, which is quite a long phrase, and not very precise (because it's the site with questions with answers).

Is there any short phrase that I can use to describe Stack Exchange?

For example:

> I'm active participant of the [phrase] called English Language Learners.

Comment: Questions and Answers implies that the two are linked based on experience with Q/A sites, even though it isn't implied via raw English.

Answer (score 5):

You pretty much answered it yourself. At the top of the page, in fact, you can find Stack Exchange's way of describing themselves:

> Stack Exchange is a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites.

Comment: When writing, OK, but when speaking? How to spell Q&A and will it be commonly understood?

Comment: @lechlukasz Question and Answer is the easiest method of saying Q&A, although you could also say each letter "Q and A"

Comment: I would expect "Q and A site" to be universally understood. That phrase has been around long enough. There are variants like "Q and A session" (generally held at the end of a meeting or conference)

Answer (score 3):

As [Squazic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/80/57), I'd call that, by order of increasing length:

- *Q&A* (3 syllables : ”Q and A”)
- *Q&A site* (4)
- *Q&A website* (5)
- *Question and Answers website* (7)
- *Website with questions and answers about English* (12)

Longer than that, you'd rather describe it enthusiastically, and invite he whom you're speaking with to join us :·)

Answer (score -3):

I agree with everything said, however if your learning English you should use the term `website` since `site` is not grammatically correct, although it is very commonly used. Q&A or Question and Answer are really very similar.

> I'm active participant of the community question and answer **website** called English Language Learners.

Comment: How is it not grammatically correct? "Site" and "website" are both common nouns and are in exactly parallel constructions here.